# SecureStorage not working in MAUI with android emulator

Tags: maui

I'm new to MAUI and i want to save a token to the secureStorage. I have the following line to save the key en get the key:

- await SecureStorage.Default.SetAsync(key, value)
- var value = await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(key);

But the app doesn't not throw a exception when setting the Key or getting the value. when it hit the line to save the key or get the key it just returns to the calling procedure.
What am i doing wrong?

```
   public static async Task SaveAsync<T>(string key, T data)
    {
        try
        {
            bool success = SecureStorage.Default.Remove(key);
            var value = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
            await SecureStorage.Default.SetAsync(key, value);
            string test = "test";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
            return;
        }
    }

    public static async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            var value = await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(key);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                return (T)default;

            var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (T)default;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the actual code and some more context. When and where are you calling those methods? Does it work on a real device?

Comment: Hi ewerspej, i have added the code. And no it doesn't work also on actual device. Am i missing some settings/configurations?

Comment: Which platform are you on? Did you follow the "Get Started" instructions in the [SecureStorage documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?tabs=android#get-started) for the respective platform(s)?

Comment: I'm develop on Windows. What do i have to do specif voor Android?

Comment: How large is the serialized data that you're trying to save? Secure storage is intended for small amounts of data. Larger data should be stored in some form of database in the app's private storage. Have you tried to just save a simple line of text to make sure that's working before attempting to write a serialized object?

Comment: Yes. I have tried to save ("Key", "Value"). But it also doesn't work.

Comment: Do a test without use of JsonSerializer calls. `await SecureStorage.Default.SetAsync("Key", "Value"); var value = await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync("Key");`  After that, what does `value` contain?

Comment: Hi ToolmakerSteve, Sorry for the late reacion. It did not work. No Exeception is thrown.

Comment: @user3552264 I've tested the `SecureStorage` on Windows and Android emulator. It worked well. BTW, what's the version of your Visual Studio, you may need to upgrade it as there's [a merged issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12341) that resembles your issue.

Comment: Hi Alexander, Tnx for your Reply. I have create a new project (dotnet 7.0) and the securestorage works. So i think it's my project that's not good. Thank you alle for your time and reply.